# Automatically download a file from a website every day

Tags: javascript, file, url, web-scraping, download

I need to download a file from this website: "https://es.investing.com/indices/merv-historical-data", automatically and every single day. To download the file I must click a js button that says "**Descargar Datos**" (or "Download Data").

I can't find something that works for this, and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Please try to provide as much information as possible for your use-case. Your comment on the answer indicates that you want to upload the data to Access, but that was not stated in the original question.
It generally helps indicating what you have already tried and read about. You suggested you can't find something, but what have you tried searching for; what has your search resulted in; etc. Using a search engine with your exact question title describes ways to do this in multiple languages. If your specific problem is that you don't know the URL that the "Download Data" button points to, ind

Comment: I want my Access database to auto fill every single day. I found a way that requires to have the file that investing provides when downloading data, so i thought that it should not be that hard to click a button on a page automatically every single day. I really think that it is the simplest way for my case, as i know its possible than learning how to code a macro for access to retrieve data from the web.
I found multiple ways to do it, but only when the file to download its a single link (like "www.example.com/download"), where just by pasting that u download the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data automatically exported in to Excel Spreadsheets, you can actually pull a table from a website. I found [this article](https://www.analytics-tuts.com/download-tables-from-any-webpage-to-excel/) about how to do it:

1. After opening a new sheet in Excel, click "Data" in the navigator bar
2. All the way to the left, there should be a button that says "From Web"
3. After clicking it, it will ask for a URL. Just copy-paste "https://es.investing.com/indices/merv-historical-data" (without quotations)
4. The first time it might ask if you want to establish an anonymous connection, just click ok.
5. Excel will then try to connect to the website, give it a few minutes.
6. You will then get a file drop down with a bunch of tables. Table 0 is what you are probably looking for. Select it and then click "Load" in the bottom right corner.

This is basically what that button did on the website. It just compiled the data and then invoked a download.

Comment: Thanks, but i need the specifically the file, because it's not for Excel, but for Access (i want it to update every single day from this website). I found a way to do that but i need the file to import the data, as i couldn't find a way to do it directly from the website.